# Alarm Manager does not fire in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, alarmmanager

I'm building an application where i need to trigger an alarm manager and the latter will trigger another notification to show some message at certain time , i have added the plugin and everything but for some reason it is not triggered ,if anyone could help , Thank you

- This is the plugin used

```
  android_alarm_manager_plus: ^2.0.5
```

- This is Manifest File

```
  //Permission 
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
    <!-- For apps with targetSDK=31 (Android 12) -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SCHEDULE_EXACT_ALARM"/>

 //Service 
 
        <service
            android:name="dev.fluttercommunity.plus.androidalarmmanager.AlarmService"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE"
            android:exported="false"/>
        <receiver
            android:name="dev.fluttercommunity.plus.androidalarmmanager.AlarmBroadcastReceiver"
            android:exported="false"/>
        <receiver
            android:name="dev.fluttercommunity.plus.androidalarmmanager.RebootBroadcastReceiver"
            android:enabled="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"></action>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

- This is my code

```
  void triggerAlarmManager() async {
    await AndroidAlarmManager.oneShotAt(DateTime.now(),1,showNotification,exact: true,wakeup: 
   true);
  }
 
  
  void showRandomMessage(){
    Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: "Some Random Message");
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to call a callback function from the alarm manager. This means you have to change (showNotification) to (showRandomMessage) when you schedule the alarm. Also you must add (@pragma('vm:entry-point')) top of callback function. You should check the developer page (https://pub.dev/packages/android_alarm_manager_plus).